# Filling jQuery Progress Bar with results from an external php file

Tags: php, jquery, progress-bar

I am calling two php files throw jQuery and ajax. I have a progress bar at the same page and I need to fill it with respect to the results of those two files. Like for example increase 10% after every function is executed.

**Progress bar in the main php file**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
            value: 80
        });
    });
    </script>
 <div class="demo">

<div id="progressbar"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript which calls the external php files**

```
$.ajax({
        //    url: 'ajax/releaseBackEnd.php',
            url: 'batch/2-release-tmp.php',
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            data: {"fId":"abc"},
            dataType: 'xml',
            error: function(){
                alert('Error loading XML document1');
            },
            success: function(data){        
                //check error
                alert("success1");
                var $error=$(data).find('error1').text();
                if($error!="0")
                {
                    messageBox("Error1",$error);
                    return;
                }

            }
        });
```

**External PHP file 2-release-temp.php**

```
<?php

/*
 * script for releasing classification
 */


require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../config.php");
require_once(TU_CLA_LIB . "/Database.php");


/* database */

$error = "";
$aDb = new Database();
if ($aDb->error) {
    print $aDb->error;
    exit;
}

/* build pathFacetsInfo for facets */

$res = $aDb->buildFacetsPath();
if (!$res) {
    print $aDb->error;
    exit;
}

/* build classification */
$res = $aDb->buildClassification();
if (!$res) {
    print $aDb->error;
    exit;   
}

print "release succeed.\n";


?>
```

Comment: How to fill the progress bar through running the PHP files. Increase its percentage whenever a new function is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, you could split your php file and call each one of them. After the result of one php file you can increase your progress bar.

Each call could look like this:

```
// buildFacetesPath.php
$.ajax({
  url: 'batch/buildFacetsPath.php',
  success: function(data){        
    var old = $("#progressbar").progressbar("value");
    $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", old+10)
  }
});

// buildClassification.php
$.ajax({
  url: 'batch/buildClassification.php',
  success: function(data){        
    var old = $("#progressbar").progressbar("value");
    $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", old+10)
  }
});
```

Your two php files could look like this:

**buildFacetesPath.php**

```
<?php
/*
 * script for releasing classification
 */

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../config.php");
require_once(TU_CLA_LIB . "/Database.php");


/* database */

$error = "";
$aDb = new Database();
if ($aDb->error) {
    print $aDb->error;
    exit;
}

/* build pathFacetsInfo for facets */

$res = $aDb->buildFacetsPath();
if (!$res) {
    print $aDb->error;
    exit;
}

?>
```

**buildClassification.php**

```
<?php
/*
 * script for releasing classification
 */

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../config.php");
require_once(TU_CLA_LIB . "/Database.php");


/* database */

$error = "";
$aDb = new Database();
if ($aDb->error) {
    print $aDb->error;
    exit;
}

/* build classification */
$res = $aDb->buildClassification();
if (!$res) {
    print $aDb->error;
    exit;   
}

print "release succeed.\n";

?>
```